# s3a + hadoop + performance tool

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, storage

i would like to measure I/O performance of object storage in Hadoop, I am accessing the data from object stroage through s3a. i used testdfsio for HDFS performance read and write throughput measurement , which does not work with s3a. please throw some light to do a I/O performance (read ,write throughput) of object storage in Hadoop via s3a connector.

regards, 
Karthik